# SAS Do loops with multiple variables

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

So I have a string with text in it for example "Jonathan Bob Thomas Smith" and I have partitioned the words into 4 variables (OLDVAR1-4) so OLDVAR1 would be Jonathan and OLDVAR2 would be Bob etc.  What I want to do is rewrite the following code with a do loop:

```
NewVar1 = Index(String,OldVar1);

NewVar2 = Index(String,OldVar2);

NewVar3 = Index(String,OldVar3);

NewVar4 = Index(String,OldVar4);
```

I have tried:

```
Array NewVar[i];

Do i = 1 to 4;

NewVar[i] = Index(String,OldVar[i]);

end;
```

but I get the error message "Undeclared array referenced OldVar" and I can't seem to do multiple references in arrays.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do what SAS says you to do: to declare array OldVar. So your code will look like:

```
Array NewVar[4];
Array OldVar[4];
Do i = 1 to 4;
    NewVar[i] = Index(String,OldVar[i]);
end;
```

BTW, you can't declare array using `i` , unless `i` already has some integer value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify an actual number of elements when declaring the array. Basic syntax is like: *`Array arrayName(no. of elements) variableList;`*
e.g.

```
data test1;
    string='Jonathan Bob Thomas Smith';
    Oldvar1='Bob';
    Oldvar2='Smith';
    Oldvar3='mas';
    Oldvar4='tha';
    ;
run;

data test2;
    set test1;
    Array NewVar(4) Newvar1-Newvar4;
    Array Oldvar(4) Oldvar1-Oldvar4;  *Additional array that's used in do loop;
    do i=1 to 4;
        NewVar[i] = Index(String,OldVar[i]);
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```